# Any incompatibility issues moving project to Java 8?

Tags: android, lambda, java-8

We have an android library which is used by customers in various projects. Most of the projects have JellyBean or KitKat as minimum SDK version. The key motivation is to use move from interface to lambda expressions and use default interface methods where we can't.

I have read the guide here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support and both the feature have no min SDK levels.

However, I'd like to know from people who went through the same path. What issues we should be prepared to encounter when we upgrade library to 1.8

thanks

Comment: why someone would mark this as negative? Is it a wrong question?

Answer (score 1):

For sure **Lambda's** and **method reference** will make your code easier to read and maintain:

Java 7:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // do some stuff
        }
```

Java 8:

```
    button.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
        // do some stuff
    }
```

**Improved type inference** will allow to remove a lot of casts. For instance:

```
TextView keyNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.key_choice_key_name_text);
```

will become:

```
TextView keyNameText = findViewById(R.id.key_choice_key_name_text);
```

---

Something might appear a bit strange at the first  glance, if the developers are used to classic Java8:

While you can write lambda's expressions in your code (because they are part of Java 8 language feature), you cannot use the interfaces usually associated with lambda's, those located in `java.util.function`, i.e.:

```
java.util.function.Function
java.util.function.Consumer
```

Because they are part of Java 8 Language API, requiring API level 24 or higher. Thus if you happen to need `java.util.function.Consumer` for instance, you will have to write your own consumer:

```
public interface MyConsumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}
```

---

That being said, the migration is quite straightforward and did not bring any regression in my case.

Comment: pardon my ignorance. Since the above mentioned google document says that lambda are supported in all the version (even before 24), what does it mean. Can't I use to replace an interface to lambda in previous versions?

Comment: @Rahul Yes you can used lambdas with api level < 24 - I just wanted to say you can't use `java.util.function.Function` for instance. This may be a bit confusing because they both came together with Java 8.

Comment: Of course you can use lamda's with all interfaces, provided that they have only one (non default) method.

Comment: We have interface with multiple methods. We plan to remove interface altogether and only use individual lambda functions for each method. Very similar to blocks in objective-c

Comment: Keep in mind that a lambda is always linked to an interface. You cannot just "remove interface altogether and only use individual lambda functions"